# Rails 6 Deep Dup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization

I have a deeply nested object, and I'd like to get a 'dup' version with one of the nested property updated.

Let's say we have a `Country`, `City`, `State`, `Person`.

`Country` has `city` and `state`. `City` has `persons`.

Below is a sample of `Country`, say `country_sample`

```
{
  "id"=>16,
  "city"=>
    [{"id"=>22,
      "person"=>
       [{"id"=>11,
         "uuid"=>"20ac322f-5f62-4786-b14b-73e4cc2a9f38",
         "updated_at"=>"2020-11-12T02:59:53.000Z"}]},
     {"id"=>23,
      "person"=>
       [{"id"=>12,
         "uuid"=>"196e8d33-9b2f-4aab-a2eb-1bda645abc31",
         "updated_at"=>"2020-11-12T02:59:53.000Z"}]},
     {"id"=>24,
      "person"=>[]}],
  "state"=>
  [{"id"=>10,
    "given_name"=>"SomeState",
    "updated_at"=>"2020-11-12T02:59:53.000Z"}],
  "other_prop"=>"val"
}
```

I need (either works):

1. I want to add a new person to the `city` with `id` `24`, and then Need a `dup` version of the whole object
2. I want to get a `dup` version and add a new person to the `city` with `id` `24`

The problem that I'm facing is:
When I run `dup_country = country_sample.dup`, I donot get the nested properties.

I get something like

```
{
  "id"=>nil,
  "city"=>[],
  "state"=>[],
  "other_prop"=>"val"
}
```

As you can see all the nested properties are not there. I tried a bunch of other gems that deal with dup like (`full_dup`, `deep_dup`, `deep_dive`), but nothing did the trick. I wonder what might be going wrong?

---

UPDATED:

While `deep_dup` works for the example posted at https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_dup , I tried on the object that I had and it still has the same effect as `dup`.

Comment: What is the type of the object your trying to dup? From your example it looks like a hash

Comment: I tried it on the main object as well as the JSON version of it. Inspecting with `.kind_of? (Hash)`, it reads the JSON is `hash`. But, `deep_dup ` on the JSON version doesnot do anything at all. It's returning the same JSON.

Comment: Can you do `.class` on the main object?

Comment: main object is `Country` . On the other hand, the json version that goes through `.as_json(:include .. nested properties` is `Hash`

Answer (score 1):

[`amoeba`](https://github.com/amoeba-rb/amoeba) gem worked well after a few changes to the model.

```rb
#config on models

# Country
class Country < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  
  amoeba do
    include-_association :city 
    include-_association :state 
  end
  ...
end

# City
class City < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  
  amoeba do
    include-_association :person 
  end
  ...
end
```

`country_deep_dupped = country.amoeba_dup` to get the `deep-dup` version that returned `dup` version of the nested objects as well.

Comment: if you all hate DSL you could use [deep_cloneable](https://github.com/moiristo/deep_cloneable)